# Trying to shorten the code for combining multiple data frames

Tags: r

I have data frames called `q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,...,q10`. And I would like to combine similar rows for every data frame into a new data frame. For example combining the first rows:

```
beta1 <- rbind(q1[1,],q2[1,],q2[1,],q3[1,],
     q4[1,],q5[1,],q6[1,],q7[1,],q8[1,],q9[1,],q10[1,])
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps: `qq <- mget( paste0("q", 1:10)); qq1 <- lapply(qq, "[", 1, NULL); do.call(rbind, qq1)`. Don't know that it is "simpler", but it certainly is more "generalizable". Could make a get_nth_row function to assist in the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(grep("^q\\d{1,2}$", ls(), value = TRUE)), "[", 1))
```